# Spree application and main rails application CSS loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have a Spree application and some pages that are not part of the spree application. My problem is that styles are shared between those pages. (they look similar, but they have their own asset locations)

How do I do it so I don't have to maintain two sets of stylesheets/JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract common stylesheets to separate CSS files then include them in your applications:

- use build process (such as Asset Pipeline)
- symlinks (not a best way but I think it will works too)
- submodules (if you are using Git)
- put common stylesheets to separate gem and use it as part of Asset Pipeline (like any Rails gems with assets inside)

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on "use build process" ? I alreade use the asset pipeline.

Comment: The common idea is to use shared place for common CSS and copy them to your projects. For example you can write script to copy common CSS to your project from one shared place before running server or deploy. The second way is to use shared directory with assets and specify path to it in Assets Pipeline (i.e. use [config.assets.paths](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#initializer-options)).